# YAML Language Support extension in VS Code detects dozens of problems in Ansible file

Tags: visual-studio-code, ansible, yaml

I am using Visual Studio Code to edit my Ansible project `.yml` files.
I have `/roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml` file with the following content:

```
- name: Install Component 1
  become: yes
  package:
    name: anypackage
    state: present

- name: Install Component 1
  become: yes
  package:
    name: otherpackage
    state: present
```

The playbook which uses this role runs with no errors.

Now I installed [YAML Language Support extension by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml), and it detects dozens of errors in this file, starting with the very first line's `n` character in `- name:`

```
"message": "Missing property "block".",
"source": "yaml-schema: Ansible Tasks Schema",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 3,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 4
```

I do understand that this file does not conform to a complete ansible playbook file's scheme, but it should not, instead it is a role's task's main.yml file. How can I enlighten the validator about this? (or do I miss something else?)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, "_a link_", probably [Schemas for Ansible and its related tools](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/tree/main/src/ansiblelint/schemas#schemas-for-ansible-and-its-related-tools). @g.pickardou, "_How can I can I enlighten the validator ..._", at least the message seems to be comming from [`repo:ansible/ansible-lint Missing property "block"`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aansible%2Fansible-lint+Missing+property+%22block%22&type=code)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, this is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml. For my defense I mentioned "by Red Hat" in my original post, and this is "the" YAML support for vscode with more than 14M downloads. I edited the original post to make it more explicit.

Comment: _For my defense_ > don't. My comment was not a judgement of the quality of your question (that's what up & down votes are for), but making the exact extension clear would avoid some annoying back and forth with a potential answer missing the proper extension. That's generally a bad idea to rely to anyone's assumption on the exact scenario you're in.

Comment: I'm also seeing `Missing property "block".`  at the very beginning of my file (maybe not so coincidentally at the 'n' in `- name: Some play`) and have the same question about resolving this message from the ansible linter.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `become: yes` to `become: true` (the [proper method](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html)) resolved this error for me.